# Using jqwidget scheduler throws Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jqxAppointment'

Tags: javascript, php, jqwidget

i am playing around with jqwidget scheduler and after i had implemented an external resource / php to get the appointments, it throws following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jqxAppointment' of undefined
    at a.(anonymous function).getJQXAppointmentByElement
```

The piece it is complain about:

```
getAppointmentElement: function(a) {
            var b = null;
            a.className.indexOf("jqx-scheduler-appointment") >= 0 && a.className.indexOf("jqx-scheduler-appointment-inner-content") == -1 && a.className.indexOf("jqx-scheduler-appointment-content") == -1 && a.className.indexOf("jqx-scheduler-appointment-resize-indicator") == -1 && (b = a);
            for (var c = a, d = 0; d < 4 && c.parentNode; d++) c.className.indexOf("jqx-scheduler-appointment") >= 0 && c.className.indexOf("jqx-scheduler-appointment-innter-content") == -1 && c.className.indexOf("jqx-scheduler-appointment-content") == -1 && c.className.indexOf("jqx-scheduler-appointment-resize-indicator") == -1 && (b = c), c = c.parentNode;
            return b
        },
        getJQXAppointmentByElement: function(a) {
            var b = this,
                c = a.getAttribute ? a.getAttribute("data-key") : a.attr("data-key");
            if (c.indexOf(".") >= 0) var d = c.substring(0, c.indexOf(".")),
                e = (c.substring(c.indexOf(".") + 1), b.appointmentsByKey[d]),
                f = e.jqxAppointment.renderedAppointments[c];
            else var e = b.appointmentsByKey[c],
                f = e.jqxAppointment; <-- COMPLAINING
            return f
        },
```

Here is my snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var source = {
            dataType: 'json',
            dataFields: [{
                    name: 'id'
                },
                {
                    name: 'description'
                },
                {
                    name: 'location'
                },
                {
                    name: 'subject'
                },
                {
                    name: 'calendar'
                },
                {
                    name: 'start'
                },
                {
                    name: 'end'
                },
                {
                    name: 'status'
                },
            ],
            url: './includes/incCalendar/test.php',
            **id:'id',**
        };
        var adapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
        $("#scheduler").jqxScheduler({
            date: new $.jqx.date('todayDate'),
            width: '100%',
            height: 600,
            rowsHeight: 50,
            dayNameFormat: "abbr",
            source: adapter,
            columns: [{
                    name: 'id',
                    datafield: 'id'
                },
                {
                    name: 'description',
                    datafield: 'description'
                },
                {
                    name: 'location',
                    datafield: 'location'
                },
                {
                    name: 'subject',
                    datafield: 'subject'
                },
                {
                    name: 'calendar',
                    datafield: 'calendar'
                },
                {
                    name: 'start',
                    datafield: 'start'
                },
                {
                    name: 'end',
                    datafield: 'end'
                },
                {
                    name: 'status',
                    datafield: 'status'
                }
            ],
            showLegend: true,
            /**
             * called when the context menu is created.
             * @param {Object} menu - jqxMenu's jQuery object.
             * @param {Object} settings - Object with the menu's initialization settings.
             */
            contextMenuCreate: function(menu, settings) {
                var source = settings.source;
                source.push({
                    id: "delete",
                    label: "Delete Appointment"
                });
                source.push({
                    id: "status",
                    label: "Set Status",
                    items: [{
                            label: "Free",
                            id: "free"
                        },
                        {
                            label: "Out of Office",
                            id: "outOfOffice"
                        },
                        {
                            label: "Tentative",
                            id: "tentative"
                        },
                        {
                            label: "Busy",
                            id: "busy"
                        }
                    ]
                });
            },
            /**
             * called when the user clicks an item in the Context Menu. Returning true as a result disables the built-in Click handler.
             * @param {Object} menu - jqxMenu's jQuery object.
             * @param {Object} the selected appointment instance or NULL when the menu is opened from cells selection.
             * @param {jQuery.Event Object} the jqxMenu's itemclick event object.
             */
            contextMenuItemClick: function(menu, appointment, event) {
                var args = event.args;
                switch (args.id) {
                    case "delete":
                        $("#scheduler").jqxScheduler('deleteAppointment', appointment.id);
                        return true;
                    case "free":
                        $("#scheduler").jqxScheduler('setAppointmentProperty', appointment.id, 'status', 'free');
                        return true;
                    case "outOfOffice":
                        $("#scheduler").jqxScheduler('setAppointmentProperty', appointment.id, 'status', 'outOfOffice');
                        return true;
                    case "tentative":
                        $("#scheduler").jqxScheduler('setAppointmentProperty', appointment.id, 'status', 'tentative');
                        return true;
                    case "busy":
                        $("#scheduler").jqxScheduler('setAppointmentProperty', appointment.id, 'status', 'busy');
                        return true;
                }
            },
            /**
             * called when the menu is opened.
             * @param {Object} menu - jqxMenu's jQuery object.
             * @param {Object} the selected appointment instance or NULL when the menu is opened from cells selection.
             * @param {jQuery.Event Object} the open event.
             */
            contextMenuOpen: function(menu, appointment, event) {
                if (!appointment) {
                    menu.jqxMenu('hideItem', 'delete');
                    menu.jqxMenu('hideItem', 'status');
                } else {
                    menu.jqxMenu('showItem', 'delete');
                    menu.jqxMenu('showItem', 'status');
                }
            },
            /**
             * called when the menu is closed.
             * @param {Object} menu - jqxMenu's jQuery object.
             * @param {Object} the selected appointment instance or NULL when the menu is opened from cells selection.
             * @param {jQuery.Event Object} the close event.
             */
            contextMenuClose: function(menu, appointment, event) {},
            exportSettings: {
                fileName: null
            },
            ready: function() {
                //   $("#scheduler").jqxScheduler('ensureAppointmentVisible', '1');
            },
            resources: {
                colorScheme: "scheme05",
                dataField: "calendar",
                orientation: "vertical",
                source: new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source)
            },
            appointmentDataFields: {
                from: "start",
                to: "end",
                id: "id",
                status: "status",
                description: "description",
                location: "location",
                subject: "subject",
                resourceId: "calendar"
            },
            dayNameFormat: "full",
            view: 'timelineDayView',
            views: [{
                    type: 'timelineDayView',
                    appointmentHeight: 25,
                    timeSlotWidth: 15,
                    appointmentsRenderMode: "exactTime",
                    timeRuler: {
                        scale: "quarterHour",
                        formatString: "HH:mm",
                        scaleStartHour: 6,
                        scaleEndHour: 23
                    }
                },
                {
                    type: 'timelineWeekView',
                    appointmentHeight: 25,
                    timeSlotWidth: 15,
                    appointmentsRenderMode: "exactTime",
                    timeRuler: {
                        scale: "quarterHour",
                        formatString: "HH:mm",
                        scaleStartHour: 6,
                        scaleEndHour: 23
                    }
                },
                {
                    type: 'timelineMonthView',
                    appointmentHeight: 25,
                    timeSlotWidth: 15,
                    appointmentsRenderMode: "exactTime",
                    timeRuler: {
                        scaleStartHour: 6,
                        scaleEndHour: 23
                    }
                },
                {
                    type: 'agendaView',
                    appointmentHeight: 50,
                    timeSlotWidth: 15,
                    appointmentsRenderMode: "exactTime",
                    timeRuler: {
                        formatString: "HH:mm",
                        scaleStartHour: 6,
                        scaleEndHour: 23
                    }
                },
                {
                    type: 'dayView',
                    appointmentHeight: 50,
                    appointmentsRenderMode: "exactTime",
                    timeRuler: {
                        scale: "quarterHour",
                        formatString: "HH:mm",
                        scaleStartHour: 6,
                        scaleEndHour: 23
                    }
                },
                {
                    type: 'weekView',
                    appointmentHeight: 50,
                    appointmentsRenderMode: "exactTime",
                    timeRuler: {
                        scale: "quarterHour",
                        scaleStartHour: 6,
                        scaleEndHour: 23
                    }
                }
            ]
        });


    });
</script>
```

> I got it, it was missing this piece in the source adapter: **id:'id',**